# Glassfish server is showing error while starting

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, websocket, glassfish

I am trying to run websocket example.

My client code is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Web Socket Implementation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="textmessage" type="text">
        <input onclick="sendmessage();" value="Send Message" type="button">
    </form>
<br><textarea id="messageTextArea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var webSocket=new   
            WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/SimpleWebSocketProj1/serverendpoindemo");
    var messageTextArea=document.getElementById("messageTextArea");
    webSocket.onopen=function(message){processOpen(message);};
    webSocket.onmessage=function(message){processMessage(message);};
    webSocket.onclose=function(message){processClose(message);};
    webSocket.onerror=function(message){processError(message);};
    function processOpen(message)
    {
        messageTextArea.value +="Server Connect.." + "\n";
    }

    function onmessage(message)
    {
        messageTextArea.value +="Receive from server..-->" + message.data   
                    +"\n";
    }

    function sendmessage()
    {   if(textmessage.vaue!="close")
            {
            webSocket.send(tesxtmessage.value);
            messageTextArea.value +="Send to server..-->" +    
                            textmessage.value +"\n";
            tesxtmessage.value="";
            }
        else 
            webSocket.close();
    }

    function processClose(message)
    {   
        webSocket.send("Client disconnceted..");
        messageTextArea.value +="Server Disconnect.." + "\n";
    }
    function processError(message)
    {
        messageTextArea.value +="Error while Connect..\n";
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my server java code

```
package com.ws.test;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/serverendpoindemo")
public class ServerEndpoinDemo 
{   @OnOpen
public void handleOpen()
{
    System.out.println("client is now connected..");
}
@OnMessage
public String handleMessage(String message)
{
    System.out.println("receive from client.." +message);
    String replymessage="echo " +message; 
    System.out.println("send to client.." +replymessage);
    return replymessage;

}
@OnClose
public void handleClose()
{
    System.out.println("client is now disconnected..");
}
@OnError
public void handleError(Throwable t)
{
    t.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

When i am trying to run on server it is showing the error like this
The Eclipse plugin cannot communicate with the GlassFish server, status is :CREDENTIAL_ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is something wrong with the installation of glassfish, make sure you have the correct filepath from your glassfish and the correct JDK in eclipse.
When you make a new dynamic web project go to: target runtime > glassfish 4 and pass the glassfish server directory: C:..\glassfish4\glassfish
Then in that same screen add a JDK instead of the JRE with the file location: C:..\Java\jdk1.7.0_51. If you don't have a JDK download it. Hit finish and it should work.

Comment: @ user3241867:i had already did it still i m not able to run ,i also tried in Eclipse indigo and Juno IDE but yet not resolved.